# change android's web browser settings programmatically

Tags: android, browser

I am doing a MDM, in this moment i am checking some features to see if these are possible to build in android, i have searched about enable/disable java script, popups and cookies programmatically but apparently the web browser is the only that manages these settings, i would like to know if someone has reached enable/disable those features throught programatically.

Answer (score 0):

See [access android stock browser settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236685/access-android-stock-browser-settings) - AFAIK no APIs exist to update these settings from within the web page (imagine the badness that a bad actor could get up to by enabling popups)