# Is it posible to change default search engine from Google.com to some other programmatically for Android browser

Tags: android, android-webview, android-preferences, android-browser, android-permissions

I need to change the default search engine from Google.com to some other for android programmatically, Or is it possible to change home page of default browser in android?

OR

Is it posible to get default browser's home page url programatically from my application

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no straight method.How about sending an intent to open a specific search engine using ACTION_VIEW.

```
String url = "http://www.yahoo.com";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

Also check out this question: [Android: change default Home Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3836215/android-change-default-home-application). It may give some insight

Comment: this is how you open browser from your application for a specific url.My question is how you can change Device in built Browser's home page programatically from your application

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, but I thing you will not be able to do so. Please go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236685/access-android-stock-browser-settings/4237151#4237151) I think it might help you.