# How to enable javascripts ,block pop ups, accept cookies in android?

Tags: android

I need to develop an android application which will:

1.enable javascripts.
2.block pop ups.
3.accept cookies in android's default browser.

I am trying for this but unable to find any suitable way for doing this.Any kind of help or suggestions will be appreciated.
Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this code will call Browser settings page from your application (note: APi14)

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MANAGE_NETWORK_USAGE);
 i.setPackage("com.android.browser");
 startActivity(i);
```

you may start from there..

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.This works greatly but i need to do the above mentioned things silently, without the interaction of user.Is there any possible way for this ??

Comment: AFAIK..this not possible for security reasons.. you can imagine its bad application..Android's operating system level security model basically prevents this..

Comment: Anyway.. you can check this link for more.. hope i helped enough

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236685/access-android-stock-browser-settings